# Replace hibernate with OpenJpa Spring-Boot Rest

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, replace, openjpa, spring-rest

I am a newbie to Spring-Boot and currently working on replacing Hibernate with OpenJPA in an existing Spring-boot REST application. When I replaced the dependencies in pom.xml, it gives an error,
    "***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.emp.service.CarhireEventService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1"
```

Below is the modified pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EmpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmpApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below is the carhireEventService class

```
@Service
public class CarhireEventService {

    private CarhireEventRepository carhireEventRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CarhireEventService(CarhireEventRepository carhireEventRepository) {
        this.carhireEventRepository = carhireEventRepository;
    }

    public CarhireEvent createCarhireEvent(String equipInitial, Integer equipNum, Date eventDateTime, String evntType) {

        return carhireEventRepository.save(new CarhireEvent(equipInitial, equipNum, eventDateTime, evntType));
    }
}
```

The application works fine with Hibernate. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot doesn't have any auto-configuration for OpenJPA. If you want to use it in place of Hibernate you'll have to write the necessary configuration yourself.